# Javascript/Firefox: window.innerHeight minimum seems to be 100px

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have a simple javascript program that's acting a little funny.  When I try to specify window.innerHeight to be under 100px, my specification is overridden and a value of 100px is used instead.

The code below does not create a  30px high inner-window as might be expected.  Instead the window is 100px. The alert similarly reads "100".

Any idea on how to fix this?

```
function loadVideo() {
    var args = fetchArguments();
    iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

    iframe.title = "YouTube video player";
    iframe.class = "youtube-player";
    iframe.type = "text/html";
    iframe.width = args["width"];
    iframe.height = args["height"];
    iframe.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + args["vid"];
    iframe.frameborder="0";
    iframe.allowFullScreen;

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(iframe); // we append the iframe to the document's body

    window.innerHeight= 30; //args["height"];
    window.innerWidth=args["width"];
    alert(window.innerHeight);
    self.focus();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox won't let you create a window of less than 100 pixels in height or width. This is a security restriction.

Answer (score 2):

You should be setting window.innerHeight/innerWidth with a number not a string. Toss a parseInt around your "args['height']" variable.

**Updated**

SoundCloud provides an direct embed for their Flash player, here's a sample of it:

```
<object height="81" width="100%"> 
  <param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F8407161"></param> 
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param> 
  <embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F8407161" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed> 
</object>
```

Note that you can set the height and width values directly on the <object> tag. So just write the embed tag out into the body of the popup, setting the popup height to 81px and width to whatever you want (at least 300px, so it looks okay).

**Updated Again**

The real question here is how you open a popup window in a browser with specific content (read html content) size. You can set the size of a popup in window.open but that will be the total size of the popup window including the browser chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll fix that.  Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem. I've edited my code above to indicate the changes I made; the problem still persists as described.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using innerHeight as opposed to just height?

Comment: The code above is simply a simplified piece of the problem I'm working on.  I'm actually attempting to embed a soundcloud audio player in a simple pop-up window.  The player interface is 80px tall.  I want a simple popup that only shows that player.  The only way I know to get the window to fit exactly the size of the player is to set "innerHeight" and "innerWidth".  My understanding is otherwise I am going to have to try to calculate the size of all of the window decorations for each browser.  Is there another way?

Comment: "setting the popup height to 81px and width to whatever you want (at least 300px, so it looks okay)."

Yup.  That's what I did.  The pop-up appears at 100px high, and the alert says the height is 100px.

Comment: ah, i gotcha. Basically you want to open a new window with a height equal to: (browser chrome height) + (soundcloud player height)